# Add column of dataframe A as a column to dataframe B

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

```
-------------------------------
dfA:
-------------------------------
                special_name
site_id                       
A               Apple
B               Banana

-------------------------------
dfB:
-------------------------------
              42      41
site_id                             
A           20944   20356
B           41795   42823
```

I need the special name column added to the dfB dataframe, so that the result is like this:

```
              42      41    special_name
site_id                             
A           20944   20356     Apple
B           41795   42823     Banana
```

I have tried:

```
dfB['special_name'] = dfA['special_name']

TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

I've also tried as many variations of merge, concat, and join as I can think of. They all have errors, so for example:

```
dfB = dfB.join(dfA, on='site_id')

KeyError: u'no item named site_id'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: actually dfB['special_name'] = dfA['special_name'] works on your example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `join` is throwing an error because `site_id` isn't exactly a column in this case - it's the DataFrame's index. You should be able to just use:

```
dfB = dfB.join(dfA)
```

By default, `join` assumes you want to join the two frames on their indexes.  By using `on=`, it started looking for the `site_id` in the DataFrame's columns.

Alternatively, you could use `merge`:

```
dfB = pandas.merge(dbA, dbB, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```